# Why my url remove "wp-content" after redirect from root domain to Subdomains?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, url, redirect

my test url is : https://mydomains.com/wp-content/uploads-webpc/uploads/2022/05/store-riil-x-1-300x404.jpg.webp

My htaccess rule is following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomains\.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomains.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I test the rule in https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ and the result is following:

[image]

> 2. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aspirecig\.com$ [NC]`
>
>    This condition was met.
> 3. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.aspirecig.com/$1 [L,R=301]`
>
>    The new url is https://www.aspirecig.com/wp-content/uploads-webpc/uploads/2022/12/black-1.jpg.webp
>
>    Test are stopped, a redirect will be made with status code 301

The browser's url is actually rewritten to: https://www.mydomains.com/uploads-webpc/uploads/2022/05/store-riil-x-1-300x404.jpg.webp

Why i lost "wp-content" ? What are the possible causes of this situation? Do Someone can help me? Thanks every much

Comment: Could there be other rewrite rules in the folder structure or in Apache config?

Answer (score 0):

When you use RewriteRule in .htaccess (or `<directory>`) some leading portion is stripped out on the string you compare to implicitly.

In the DocumentRoot, it's the leading "/". One directory deeper, like wp-content/ in the document root, it's going to have that directory that lead you there stripped off too.

So, if this htaccess is in `$docroot/wp-content` then `/wp-content` is stripped off.  If you want to get back to the full original URL, avoid $1 here and use `%{REQUEST_URI}`.